# How can I transform struct to POST data in Go?

Tags: http, go

I need to send a POST request to a server. I found that this is done like this:

```
  body := &bytes.Buffer{}
  writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)

  // Repeat these two lines for every field
  x, _ := writer.CreateFormField("field")
  x.Write([]byte("value"))

  writer.Close()

  r, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://example.com", body)
  r.Header.Add("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
  client := &http.Client{}
  client.Do(r)
```

Now I have a struct containing all the fields. How can I transform the struct to the POST body? As in I want to call something that would process the struct and do the CreateFormField calls.

Note that the struct may contain nested fields and arrays so it's not exactly straightforward.

Also note that I can't simply POST a JSON because I'm also uploading some files so this needs to be a multipart/form-data request. I found some examples how to do file upload (even with multiple large files) so I think I can handle that part. I just need to create the POST request body from my struct.

Comment: Sounds like you control the server side as well. You could post JSON and encode the files as base64, if you can live with the 33% size increase. You could use [BSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON) or some other serialization format with good binary support. Otherwise you will need to devise some way to map your nested struct fields to flat form fields, and back again, which is just busywork.

Comment: No I do not control the server. It's a 3rd party API.

Comment: Ah, then you have an even better reason for not being able to POST a JSON. But then, what does the server expect the multipart form data to look like?

Comment: Just a standard POST format as if you sent a form.

Comment: HTML forms never send Go structs with nested fields and arrays.

Comment: HTML forms can have nested fields and arrays just fine. The struct is just my representation of the data in the script.

Comment: HTTP POST does not support nested fields and only implicitly supports arrays (by providing the same field multiple times). HTTP POST only allows for a flat set of keys and values. The API you're calling may interpret keys or values in some particular way to emulate nested fields or arrays, but that will be entirely dependent on that implementation; it is not part of the HTTP standard.

Comment: Technically correct but it's very common for servers to support `x[y][z]` as nested value syntax and `key[]` for arrays. While it's not a HTTP standard it's a de-facto standard. In practice I see little difference.